# ambiguity of `<<-` when defining it for `x < y <- z`

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

@g-grothendieck's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744379/assigning-a-value-to-a-list-item-using-assign/53745177#53745177) inspired me to play with some assignment functions such as `==<-` or `><-`.

See the following :

```
`><-` <- function(e1,e2,value) replace(e1, e1 > e2, value)
x <- c(5,15)
x > 10 <- 42
x
# [1]  5 42
```

I can also define it for `<` :

```
`<<-` <- function(e1, e2, value) replace(e1, e1 < e2, value)
x <- c(5,15)
x < 10 <- 42
x
# [1] 42 15
```

But the problem is that now the `<<-` operator is redefined and this doesn't work anymore :

```
x <<- "hello"
```

> Error in replace(e1, which(e1 < e2), value) :    argument "value" is
>   missing, with no default

Interestingly `x < y <- z` calls `<<-` even when it's not been overwritten.

```
rm(`<<-`)
x < 10 <- 42
```

> Error in x < 10 <- 42 : incorrect number of arguments to "<<-"

Would there be a way to keep the original behavior of `<<-` while still defining this custom behavior ?

Comment: "But the problem is that now the <<- operator is redefined and this doesn't work anymore" Nice, kill two birds with one stone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
`<<-` <- function(e1, e2, value){
  if(missing(value)) 
    eval.parent(substitute(.Primitive("<<-")(e1, e2)))
  else 
    replace(e1, e1 < e2,value)
}

x <- c(5,15)
x < 10 <- 42
x
# [1] 42 15

x <<- "hello"
x
# [1] "hello"
```